# oh-my-zsh theme doesn't seem to update unless I re-launch zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've begun making my own `oh-my-zsh` theme, but I've run into a bit of a problem. I'm trying to change the color of the git output based on the name of the branch, and it works fine except for one important caveat: it changes the color to the correct one when `zsh` launches, but never re-evaluates what the color should be unless I re-launch `zsh`.

Here's a screenshot of the problem in action:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[Here's a gist with my current `zsh` theme](https://gist.github.com/Kerrick/256ed11130edb834d936).

Am I doing something wrong, or does `oh-my-zsh` or `zsh` not support this kind of thing?

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used oh-my-zsh (uh-oh) but I do use zsh and it and other shells do **not** reload configuration files between commands. You must explicitly reload them with the source command:

```
source ~/.zsh_config_file_you_modified_or_another_file
```

or

```
. ~/.zsh_config_file_you_modified_or_another_file
```

Starting a new zsh shell does that (completely with a new login shell, partially with a new sub shell as you did in the right pane above).

The complete list of which zsh config files are loaded on login vs normal shells is:

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════╗  
║                ║Interactive║Interactive║Script║  
║                ║login      ║non═login  ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║/etc/zshenv     ║    A      ║    A      ║  A   ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║~/.zshenv       ║    B      ║    B      ║  B   ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║/etc/zprofile   ║    C      ║           ║      ║   
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣   
║~/.zprofile     ║    D      ║           ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║/etc/zshrc      ║    E      ║    C      ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║~/.zshrc        ║    F      ║    D      ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║/etc/zlogin     ║    G      ║           ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║~/.zlogin       ║    H      ║           ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║                ║           ║           ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║                ║           ║           ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║~/.zlogout      ║    I      ║           ║      ║  
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════╣  
║/etc/zlogout    ║    J      ║           ║      ║  
╚════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════╝
```

If the files exist, they are loaded in A first, then B, C, D etc. I and J are only loaded/run on logging out / exiting a login shell.